# Compiling \begin{align} environment is messed up when you have a skipped line?

Tags: spacing, align, vertical-spacing

I'm learning LaTeX and writing code on overleaf.

This code with a skipped line does not work, it only outputs the second sentence without any formatting ...

```
\begin{align}
    This is my first sentence.\\
    
    This is my second sentence.    
\end{align}
```

[image]

But this code with a comment placed on the skipped line works and returns the string with math formatting ... why?

> ```
> \begin{align}
>     This is my first sentence. \\
>     %
>     This is my second sentence.
> \end{align}
> ```

[image]

Comment: Empty lines are not allowed inside of the `align` environment and other math environments.

Comment: Apart from that, I hope "This is my ... sentence" is just a placeholder for a math equation. Please don't use `align` for text, but just for math.

Comment: @leandriis 
RE comment1: Oh okay. Thanks for that. I couldn't find that statement anywhere. ||
RE comment 2: it works the same way with math. if i have a skipped line. it only shows the second line

Comment: Additionally, leaving a blank line in align gives an error. Don't just ignore compilation errors. We **have** asked overleaf to make compilation errors much much more obvious for the user other than a red button.